# Which function is better suited to retrieve the basename of a file in PHP: basename or pathinfo?

Tags: php, string, file

What's the recommended way of grabbing the basename (file name without extension) of a file in PHP?

```
echo basename('foo.jpg', '.jpg');
// outputs "foo"

echo pathinfo('foo.jpg', PATHINFO_FILENAME);
// outputs "foo"
```

Apparently both produce the same output. What are the advantages of using one over the other?

Performance wise it looks like `basename()` is faster by approximately 300ms over 1,000,000 iterations:

```
<?php

$f = 'foo.jpg';
$n = 1000000;

$start = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    basename($f);
}

$stop1 = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}

$stop2 = microtime(true);

echo "Basename result: " . ($stop1 - $start) . " seconds\n";
echo "Pathinfo result: " . ($stop2 - $stop1) . " seconds\n";
```

This outputs:

```
Basename result: 1.0358278751373 seconds
Pathinfo result: 1.3277871608734 seconds
```

Besides the marginal performance gains, I'm also interested on how are these functions implemented behind the scenes? Is the underlying algorithm for retrieving the basename similar in both cases?

Comment: `pathinfo('foo.jpg', PATHINFO_FILENAME);`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you consider pathinfo better than basename?

Comment: I find pathinfo better because I get more information. Assume this path variable: `$path = "/some/file/path.php";` and I went to get the filename without the extension. I can use `pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);` which returns *path* whilst `basename($path)` return *path.php*. Ofcourse, `basename()` would be better if you just need the basename (path.php). http://3v4l.org/2HJla

Comment: This question is not opinion-based as I'm looking for answers which cover hard facts and examples. I'm also interested in which scenarios is one function preferred over the other.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want the basename, then use the basename function. As always in any case, try to use the less consuming operation; why to create an array of info you won't need (using pathinfo) when you can get what you want in a string directly (with basename function)?

Comment: I've updated my question with a quick benchmark. `basename` is indeed faster but not by much. This marginal performance gain does not seem sufficient to make someone use one over the other, especially when dealing with a low number of filenames.

Comment: Great info. In low volume is almost nothing, but 30% increase could be a big problem in a bigger situation.

Answer (score 0):

i would probably use pathinfo as this can return an array of details of the file eg:

```
$file_info = pathinfo('foo.jpg');

$dir_path = $file_info['dirname']; // outputs /path/to/foo
$base_name = $file_info['basename']; // outputs foo.jpg
$ext = $file_info['extension']; // outputs jpg
$file_name = $file_info['filename']; // outputs foo
```